# Can not import multiple sparkcontexts

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

Please find my below problem and kindly help.

I am very new to spark. I got a work suddenly to do POC on exporting hive table to sql sever by using pyspark. So i started with some sample tutorials while practicing i imported pyspark package "`import pyspark`" in python shell and thorws an error like "Can not import SQLContext" and sometimes i use to get an error like "can not import multiple sparkcontexts" when i issued a command like "`from pyspark import SparkContext`"

Please look on below image.

[image: Error Image]

Kindly prvoide solution to get rid of it. I looked into other solutions in SO but not solves my problem.

Comment: U need to enter pyspark shell instead of python..

Comment: @TahaNaqvi Thank you for reply :). I entered pyspark in shell. that also throws same error for me "Can not import name SQLcontext". Any help on this pls?

Comment: u dont need to import it will be there already..just run the sql code.

Comment: @TahaNaqvi Just i wrote pyspark on shell and hit Enter button and that gives me the above error. I believe you got it now. :)

Comment: No ...do this : ---  bash-4.2$ pyspark